# InDesign: image gets cropped when i try to move it around

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, file-placing

New to InDesign. When I place an image in Indesign and try to move it on the page I lose whatever part of the image to the direction I move it. Like it disappears behind a clipping mask. How do I move the photo and not have parts disappearing on me?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything in InDesign is inside of boxes except text. You can either move the whole box or just the content inside of that box.

In order to move the whole box you just need to use the Selection-Tool (the "black" cursor) and move your image. You used the Direct Selection (the "white" cursor).

Comment: Further: when you select with the direct select tool (aka the "content" tool), the border turns orange as in the screenshot. If the border is blue, you are in Selection mode ("box mode")

Comment: Doesn't matter which one I select immediately after placing the image, it still moves the image inside the frame and not the frame.  The trick seems to be to select something else (or click off-canvas to select nothing), then reselect the image: then it works with the black arrow.  (This is with CS2014.)

Answer (score 2):

Select your object. In the menu bar select Object > Fitting > Fit Frame to Content (Command-Option-C). This will get the frame back to its original position.

According to your photo you are using the direct selection tool (white arrow) which selects either just the frame or just the contents, rather than the selection tool (black arrow) which selects the entire box, inside and outside.

Comment: Yeah but the OP is asking how to move the photo without it being cropped, not how to re-frame a cropped image.

Comment: Oh, so they may be selecting it with the direct selection tool (white arrow) rather than the selection tool (black arrow).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already posted but since you're new at this let me give you an extra hand. What you need to do is use the first arrow (not the second) from the vertical toolbar on the left edge of your screenshot. You can also select this tool by hitting <kbd>V</kbd> on your keyboard.

The first arrow selects the image container, while the second arrow selects the image inside the container. This is also explained in detail in the official [support pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/selecting-objects.html).

Comment: Perfect. Being much better at Illustrator. I should (duh) have been able to figure this out --Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the photo/image box and not the bounding box. There are two boxes created. When you select the photo inside the bounding box and start to move it, it disappears as you move it out of the bounding box. Make sure you select the outer bounding box, click and hold until it flashes to live scroll it to a new location.

Answer (score 0):

object -> fitting -> frame fitting options, uncheck autofit box

Using Auto Fit
If you resize an image frame when Auto-Fit is not selected, the frame resizes while the image size remains the same. If you select Auto-Fit, the image resizes with the frame. If you decide to crop or transform the image, use the Direct Selection tool to transform the image itself. Or, deselect Auto-Fit, transform the image, and select Auto-Fit again.

You can select the Auto-Fit option in the Control bar and in the Frame Fitting Options dialog box.

https://helpx.adobe.com/in/indesign/using/frames-objects.html#fitting_objects_to_frames